# Anybody know why video games are causing my internet to drop out? (but nothing else is)

Tags: router, lag

Around 24 hours ago I started having troubles with my modem and/or router, where playing video games would cause my connection to drop in and out constantly, about 15 seconds on, 15 seconds off. Everything else is working perfectly fine (including torrenting and streaming 1080p youtube videos)

The router is a TP-Link TL-WR1043ND and the modem is a Netgear CG814WGv3 with the wireless and routery stuff disabled.

The connection is wireless, but I'm not seeing any sort of outages or connection issues. This only ever happens when gaming.

Here's what a 'ping 192.168.1.1 -t' looks like during normal operation (this is while torrenting and streaming youtube videos)

```
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=30ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
```

Here's what it looks like while gaming

```
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=542ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=276ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=6ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=22ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=35ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=71ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=39ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=12ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=92ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=392ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2694ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=407ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=988ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1380ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=703ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=133ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=170ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=5ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=16ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=15ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=90ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=11ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=7ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=50ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1966ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=2541ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3455ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3020ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=3957ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=1050ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=104ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.1: bytes=32 time=297ms TTL=64
```

Here's a speedtest (this is completely normal for my connection.)

http://www.speedtest.net/result/2600329257.png

Does this look like anything anyone has seen before? I've had standard router issues before, but I've never, ever seen a problem that's caused by gaming and not by downloading torrents at 1.5MB/s or by streaming 1080p Youtube videos...

Comment: What games are you playing? If you're playing online games with heavy bandwidth usage, you might find your connection struggled by both gaming and torrenting at the same time.

Comment: I'm not torrenting at the same time as gaming. The main culprit is Path of Exile, dropouts start within 20 seconds of the game loading and are constant. League of Legends is dropping out quite a bit too, but not near as much.

Comment: Your getting packet drops pinging your router here?

Comment: Correct, I'm getting packet drops pinging my router. But only ever while gaming.